# Convert timepicker format "mm:ss" to miliseconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string in the `timepicker` format "`mm:ss`", I would like to convert this to milliseconds so I can include it in a `setTimeOut`. Here is an example of what I intend to do.

```
let minSeconds="03:30";
let milisenconds= convertMinSeconds(minSeconds)

setTimeout((){
 console.log("finish");
},milisenconds)
```

I don't know if there is an effective way to do this using javascript.

How can I do it?
thank you very much

Comment: Split the string into minutes and seconds, parse them as numbers, multiply them by the number of milliseconds that a min/second contains and add them together. Have you made an attempt yourself? If so it would be worth including it in the question.

Comment: @DBS sorry for the confusion, my question is more oriented to if javascript already has something for that, this is what I want to do

Comment: Could you share a link to a definition of the "`timepicker` format" like the GitHub repository or documentation? Or did you just make that up?

Comment: @Rojo is just format mm:ss for example : 03:30. (03 min. 30 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```js
let minSeconds="03:30";
let milisenconds= convertMinSeconds(minSeconds)
function convertMinSeconds(minSeconds) {
  let splitted = minSeconds.split(':')
  let min = Number(splitted[0])
  let second = Number(splitted[1])
  let allInSecond = min*60 + second
  let inMilisecond = allInSecond * 1000
  return inMilisecond
}

setTimeout(() => {
 console.log("finish");
},milisenconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

this function will solve the problem

```js
const ms = (time)=>{
 const [min , sec] = time.split(':')
 return  ms = ((Number(min) * 60) + Number(sec)) * 1000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
node
let minSeconds="03:30";
undefined
let miliseconds=new Date("1970-01-01T00:" + minSeconds + "Z").getTime()
undefined
console.log(miliseconds)
210000
undefined
```

```
node --version
v10.19.0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 